# Does Visual Studio 2008 Professional have a built-in graphing library?

Tags: c#, com, vb6

I am porting a VB6 application to C#.

The VB6 app uses the csXgraph graphing library. I have no clue how to access COM objects using C# and don't know if it is even the best idea to do it this way.

Does Visual Studio already have some kind of built-in graphing library that I can use with a SQL server database handling the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft offers a free .Net charting library.

[Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) **|** [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to draw a chart of data on screen? Have you seen the .NET 4 (runs on 3.5 too if you install a GAC component) DataVisualization Library?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.aspx

Comment: Since you accepted the answer of someone who gave you the exact download, I didn't think it was necessary to give you further answers. Unless you would like to remove the answer from them and assign it to me, in which case I can duplicate their answer.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2008 does not come with any built-in graphing libraries for you to use.

Luckily, .NET does make it very easy to use existing COM libraries via [COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kew41ycz%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

If, after reading about COM Interop, you decide you don't want to deal with the hassle you could also try a third-party library like [.NET Chart](http://www.componentxtra.com/) from ComponentXtra.

Answer (score 1):

Not built in, but if you are looking to chart some data they do have a free charting control that handles a number of common charting needs.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en[1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en)